# How to get Google Play Services back

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, google-play-services

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2. Recently I was trying to clear space, so I deleted a whole bunch of apps. I deleted Google Play Services, not knowing its function. I have since tried to reinstall Google Play Services, but it won't let me. I think I must have accidentally uninstalled something else that allowed Google Play Services to be installed. Anyway I don't know how to fix this problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In the usual way: Restoring from the backup you surely made before tampering with system stuff. Though usually, *GSF* re-installs itselt via Play, unless you removed some other important stuff "not knowing its function". In that case, and if you really made no backup before dealing with "the unknown": [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Answer (score -2):

Wow, I figured it out!

I just had to go back to *Settings*, then *Applications*, then *All*, and then enable Google Play Services again! I hadn't deleted it after all! Yay!